# How does the "trap-and-emulate" technique work in type 2 hypervisor?

Tags: operating-system, hypervisor

I'm reading the "Virtual Machine" chapter of the operating system concepts book.

It said "**When the kernel in the guest attempts to execute a privileged instruction, that is an error (because the system is in user mode) and causes a trap to the VMM in the real machine. The VMM gains control and executes (or emulates) the action that was attempted by the guest kernel on the part of the guest. It then returns control to the virtual machine.**"

If It is a type 1 hypervisor, I think when the guest OS executes a privileged instruction, it will trap to the OS and the OS can emulate it in kernel mode correctly because type 1 hypervisor is either an OS with VMM features or an OS designed for virtualization.

But if the case is type 2 hypervisor, it's just a normal user process, right? How can a user process emulate a privileged instruction? through system call ? But I think there are some instructions cannot be emulated by system call?

Can anyone explains this for me? Thanks a lot. T_T

Comment: Note that there is no standard meaning for 'type 1' and `type 2' -- different books will have different definitions.  So at the least, you should mention which book you're looking at and what its definitions of these are...

Comment: Modern hypervisors (of either type) don’t run the guest kernel in user mode. I think your book is very out of date.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have a user-mode 'hypervisor', it's emulating all the privileged state of the hardware, not actually running it on real hardware.  So it can emulate the effect of the privileged instruction on the emulated hardware without needing any privileged instructions of its own.

Answer (score 0):

It varies by architecture, but a common privileged instruction might be to read from a device register, maybe a serial port.   The guest OS might have code that does something like:

```
   load   UART_STATUS, r0
   and    $1, r0
   jz     $-8   // back to load status
   load   UART_DATA, r0
   ret
```

So, in this, the two load instructions would be privileged;   the vm monitor might decipher the first one as something like:

```
if (ioctl(serfd, FIONREAD, &count) != -1) {
    state->r0 = (count != 0);
} else {
    raise_error(state, ENXIO); /* or somesuch... */
}
```

and the second one into something like:

```
unsigned char ch = dont_leak_uninit_value;
if (read(serfd, &ch, 1) >= 0) {
    state->r0 = ch;
} else {
    raise_error(state, ENXIO); /* ... */
}
```

So whatever tty/file/socket/... was hooked up to serfd would source and sink an emulated serial port.

The case is a bit trickier for things like the interrupt state, because most cpus are kinda crap. Abstractly, a machine can provide a “virtual interrupt status” which is maintained by the guest, but doesn’t actually affect interrupts of the machine.  Thus it can use privileged instructions to set and clear this state at will, since it really affects nothing.  The VMM merely has to insure that this “virtual status” is saved and restored for the guest appropriately.   Most such privileged instructions can be handled, or emulated, in a similar fashion.